# Not find function dtwclust R

Tags: r

I am testing the example of the dtwclust library tutorial and having loaded the libraries it does not find the dtwclust function. Do you know what it could be?

```
> # Testing several values of k
> kc.l2 <- dtwclust(data, k = 2:4,
              distance = "L2", centroid = "pam",seed = 3247, control = ctrl)
Error in dtwclust(data, k = 2:4, distance = "L2", centroid = "pam", seed = 3247,  : no se pudo encontrar la función "dtwclust"
```

Comment: That's the name of the *package* not of a *function* in the package.

Comment: I don't understand because in the documentary of that library, dtwclust is a function. This is the example:

data(uciCT)

ctrl <- new("dtwclustControl", trace = TRUE)
# Reinterpolate to same length and coerce as matrix
data <- t(sapply(CharTraj, reinterpolate, newLength = 180))
# Subset for speed
data <- data[1:20, ]
labels <- CharTrajLabels[1:20]

kc.l2 <- dtwclust(data, k = 2:4,
distance = "L2", centroid = "pam",
seed = 3247, control = ctrl)

sapply(kc.l2, randIndex, y = labels)
plot(kc.l2[[3L]])

Comment: Looks like they got rid of the `dtwclust` function. It was definitely a function in version [3.1.1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dtwclust/versions/3.1.1/topics/dtwclust). Maybe they just forgot to update the example.